# How to configure multiple Oidc providers in IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm using IdentityServer to handle external authentication and authorizations. For that I'm using `AddOpenIdConnect`:

```
    .AddOpenIdConnect(oidcProviderOptions.AuthScheme, oidcProviderOptions.DisplayName, options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
            options.Authority = oidcProviderOptions.Uri;
            options.ClientId = oidcProviderOptions.ClientId;
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            if (oidcProviderOptions.AdditionalScopes != null) 
            {
                oidcProviderOptions.AdditionalScopes.ToList().ForEach(s => options.Scope.Ad);
            }
        });

    // preserve OIDC state in cache (solves problems with AAD and URL length)
        services.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache(oidcProviderOptions.AuthScheme);
```

If I'm calling this method twice, with different options (azure active directory and okta) I'm getting `Invalid token` errors upon connecting. Is there an error in above configuration or this is not the way to implement this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because each one will need a different `RemoteAuthenticationOptions.CallbackPath` to be defined. If they share the same path then it's probably a case of "first to be invoked wins". E.g.:

Scheme A:

```
...
options.CallbackPath = "signin-oidc/a";
...
```

Schema B:

```
...
options.CallbackPath = "signin-oidc/b";
...
```

Comment: And the `options.SignoutCallbackPath` should be specified as well.